как получить строки из процесса как в программе Process Hacker [С++/Python]
я хочу написать приложение которое выводит строки находящиеся в памяти процесса так же как это реализовано в Process Hacker, но нигде не могу найти нужную информацию. Я вижу это как функцию которая получает PID и возвращает все найденные в процессе строки.

а в программе strings как-то иначе сделано?

ничего не понял. можно поподробнее?

Вы хотите, чтоб за вас по факту написали программу. По сути вам нужно дергать много WinApi функций, от получения доступа к памяти процессу, до полного анализа этой памяти. Очень много функций. Я бы даже сказал, что вопрос нужно делить
